# Android Views vs. iOS Views

Tags: android, ios, xml

What's the fundamental difference between how views are laid out in Android versus iOS? I've created a couple apps in Android, with the views designed solely in XML, yet I have not encountered an Android counterpart to the grid-based drawing mechanisms I so frequently use in iOS. When creating a custom view in Android, I would usually just programmatically create a LinearLayout or what have you, and then instantiate the requisite components and voila. However, I've gotten accustomed to the usage of programmatic drawing of views/view controllers in iOS, which usually entails some logic like this

```
    let profileFrame = CGRectMake(0, 48, 80, 80)
    profileImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: profileFrame)
    self.addSubview(profileImageView)
    self.bringSubviewToFront(profileImageView)
```

So does there exist an analogue to this sort of view frame creation/placing within superviews in Android? Or does the XML nature of Android layouts prevent this sort of capability?

Comment: "When creating a custom view in Android, I would usually just programmatically create a LinearLayout or what have you, and then instantiate the requisite components and voila." - So you've programmatically created layouts in Android, but you're asking how to programmatically create layouts in Android?

Comment: As I understand, you want an equivalent to `frame` UIView from iOS to Android, aren't you? Because you question is a quite bit unclear, I don't really get it. Does [android.graphics.Rect Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect(int,int,int,int)) in Android might what you looking for?

Comment: I'm asking how to programmatically draw a view in a nature similar to iOS where you add subviews to a superview as opposed to adding XML elements. I didn't ask how to programmatically create layouts in Android...there are three sentences that end with question marks in my post "What's the fundamental difference between how views are laid out in Android versus iOS?...So does there exist an analogue to this sort of view frame creation/placing within superviews in Android? Or does the XML nature of Android layouts prevent this sort of capability?" none of which ask that question.

Comment: @Filo, that answers one part of my question, but from there how do you add it to a superview/add subviews?

Comment: Refer to the [docs for `ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). There are analogous methods for both `addSubview()` and `bringSubviewToFront()`. Honestly, though, if you've "create[d] a LinearLayout or what have you, and then instantiate[d] the requisite components", don't you already know this?

Comment: I mean, sort of, but my question is a bit more nuanced than that. I've never dealt with raw numbers in a coordinate plane when creating Android views, and that was the analogous functionality I was searching for. I've done something like this

   `LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.main);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    myLayout.addView(myButton);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is AbsoluteLayout.  Except you probably don't really want to do it.  Please note that there's very few good reasons to use it and a lot of reasons not to.  The main one being screen sizes and density differences between devices make it almost impossible to get right without a LOT of discipline.  The reason it works for iOS is that the limited number of device sizes and density makes the UI far simpler and the background OS can handle it.  Not the case here, you'd have to do it yourself.

You can also programatically create LinearLayouts, RelativeLayouts, etc in code.  Its just not generally recommended-  its far harder to read and edit quickly.  There are situations where its useful/necessary though.